# Is there a script to re-stack objects in illustrator by distance from top left?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, script, games

This is ideal for the creation of isometric graphics.
You can replicate an isometric tile symbol with a graphic in it, like a house or a tree, multiple times, then run the script to re-stack all selected objects (symbols).
This is necessary so their overlaps are correct, matching the faux perspective of an isometric game.

I'm sure I used one years ago to create an isometric forest but I can no longer find the script in my files, nor online.

I'm considering writing it myself but if anyone can remember where the script is that would be a lot easier!

Thank you.

ps- I guess I'd have to use Math.abs to write such a script as the Y-axis in Illustrator is inverted. No idea yet how to get an objects z-index reordered though.

Comment: There is no z - index in illustrator. Only file order. So you just use the move command to move it before or after another object in the hierarchy. This bodes bad for any group or layer.

Comment: So there's no way to refer to depth/z-index/stack order, whatever, in AI js?
I'm off to look through the books.
If I get a simple script together I'll post here again.

Comment: I didnt say that, i said there is no z-index. Order is strictly a feature of where in document something is. So if its before another object in the document tree then its drawn first. This means that you can only do this if your document has no layers or groups since objects get drawn in the document order to sort youd have to break these features or ignore them. The object.move command is there to facilitate this. (Move does not move objects in space but in hierarchy, translate moves objects in space)

Comment: Also there is no way to find the furthest point of a object in some direction since there is no evaluation functions for beziers so youd need to euther write your own slow bezier functions, rotate scene or use some other proxy.  If you can overcome the limitations with rules of the object order and use a proxy for the sorting distance its pretty trivial to write a O( N log N) loop to do this. I cant just decide implementation details to you.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to this one as I know it can be done and has been done before. The object.move tip is great, thanks @joojaa, it might be just the command I need. By z-index I was just trying to refer to stacking order / visual depth in a way that would be easily understood by a wide range of potential readers. I think the script will be very short for this one 

Comment: Yeah it can be done with some border cobstraints i would have done it if my android supported illustrator. Z-order is different though, in z-order documents like svg drawing order does not have to follow document order. This would let you preserve logical units separate from sorting. Which is not possile in illustrator.

Comment: Just dug out a very old Wiley Adobe Scripting book and it literally fell open at a whole page dedicated to actual z-index! Maybe they removed z-index from AI scripting at some point but I suspect it's rather that I've been down this road before ten years ago and totally forgotten everything. 

Comment: yeah there is a readonly variable telling youhow many objects are below you. You can not change it though. This isnt spectacularily interesting since its also the index of the object your iterating

Comment: I mean if you were writing svg then you could just override this value.

Comment: The book I have says it's the ideal way to change the stack order of objects in a layer or group programmatically. We'll find out tomorrow if that's misleading.

Comment: It seems your right. But just within a layer or group. Which means not real stacking order just relative stacking. Obj move can arange even outside groups and layers

Comment: There's a (some say it's faulty) zOrder method of a layer:
  /**
   * Arranges the layer relative to other layers.
   * @param zOrderCmd How to arrange the layer.
   */
  zOrder(zOrderCmd: ZOrderMethod): void

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive implementation that sorts by each object in *selection*. It ignores groups and layers. It actually sorts by the furthest point along angle

[image]

```
#target Illustrator

{
    var sel = app.selection;    
    generateComparasion(sel);
    sel.sort(sortByComp);
    stack(sel);
}

//====== Support funcs ==========

function sortByComp(a,b){
     return (a.comp > b.comp) ? -1 : 1    
}

// Rotate object to ange to find its furthest point along axis. then rotate it back
function generateComparasion(sel){
    var angle= 30.0;
    var rotation = app.getRotationMatrix(angle);
    var counter = app.getRotationMatrix(-angle);

    
     var len = sel.length;
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var item = sel[i];
        item.transform(rotation, true, false, false, false, 1.0, Transformation.DOCUMENTORIGIN );
        item.comp=item.position[1]+ item.height;
        item.transform(counter, true, false, false, false, 1.0, Transformation.DOCUMENTORIGIN );
   }
}

function stack(sel){
     var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];
    var len = sel.length;
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var item = sel[i];
        item.move(layer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING  )
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Nice use of maths @joojaa ! I have a screen grab of the result on a simple test file (8 tree symbols in a layer) that shows how the last object is not ordered correctly by this script, though the rest of the objects are perfectly arranged. If only I could post an image here 

Comment: @runninghead it may be that the rotating trick does not really work with symbols well, but i might have made a bug when i made the cleanup of the code too. I must test

Comment: (@runninghead, you can upload your image on [imgur](https://imgur.com/) by clicking "New post" and then link to it in your comment like described in the "help" link below.)

Comment: @joojaa, I mean click "New post" on *imgur*!

Comment: @Wolff yes but you can just edit or make an answer use the link image copy the code and cancel the edit. Does the same thing dont have to leave the webpage. So you can decide mid comment to add a image.

Comment: Loving getting back in to scripting and I love that stack function @joojaa.
Thanks for the advice @Wolff, I'll try the adjusted method later here just to see how it works. btw: I'm trying something today that I like (though it may not be the best way to achieve the required result); Giving each object a score to indicate how far forward they should be in iso perspective. `score = Math.round(sel[i].left + Math.abs(sel[i].top));`

Comment: @runninghead it may be better to use the base point of a sybol as the metric rather than shape extents.

Comment: https://imgur.com/PNK415p This may work for images, testing.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa, I'm looking forward to learning more about 'sort' later today. Not sure which is better for positional reference in this context- base point or top&left? Anyone familiar with isometric artwork, please offer an opinion on this here 

Comment: @runninghead ok i know what the problem is. Ill fix it on monday.

Comment: Anyone know how to sort an array based on values contained in nested arrays?

By this I mean- I have a long array of many short sub-arrays, eg- an array for lots of people, in which each entry is a three value array containing Job, Gender, Age.

I need to sort all items in the big array, based on the Ages of the entries.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Just not cracked it yet but here's some handy reference for anyone who fancies having a go. Image showing the ordering of the symbols BEFORE the script runs:
https://imgur.com/a/ACEVGRP    
Here's the scores for each symbol, based on `score = Math.round(sel[i].left + Math.abs(sel[i].top));`

Here's the data for the symbols (which also gives the order that they should appear in the stack IF the script is running well):

symbol 2: 1072
symbol 4: 1065
symbol 0: 1006
symbol 5: 996
symbol 3: 919
symbol 1: 896
symbol 6: 821
symbol 7: 743

Comment: Was just considering using Y axis only (or at least first, then re-stacking the result based on X axis) when I found this thread :
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8151/how-do-i-sort-isometric-sprites-into-the-correct-order

Comment: Now I've checked the outputs of `function sortByScore(a,b)` it seems it's not reordering the `sel` array based on the comparison at all. Not sure why yet.

Comment: @runninghead if you dont assign the score to the object then there is nothing to sort. Or if you do it inline you need to feturn a true or false

Comment: Think this might be it. Seems to work!
`var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var sel = docRef.selection;
function sortByScore(a,b){
     var scoreA = Math.round(Math.abs(a.top));
     var scoreB = Math.round(Math.abs(b.top));
     return (scoreA-scoreB);
}
sel.sort(sortByScore);

function stack(sel){
    var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];
    var len = sel.length;
    for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
     var item = sel[i];
        item.move(layer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
    }   
 }

 stack(sel);`

Comment: If no-one points out a flaw in my code in the next 48 hours I'll mark it as the Correct Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var sel = docRef.selection;
function sortByScore(a,b){
   var scoreA = Math.round(Math.abs(a.top));
   var scoreB = Math.round(Math.abs(b.top));
   return (scoreA-scoreB); }
sel.sort(sortByScore);
function stack(sel){
     var layer = app.activeDocument.layers[0];
     var len = sel.length;
     for (var i=0;i<len;i++){
         var item = sel[i];
         item.move(layer, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);     
     }
 }
 stack(sel);
```